# How do I delete/replace the previously drawn polyline so that at any given time there is only one present?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ideally, I want a single line that is drawn from the closest marker to the static position. I can sort the distances to find which marker is the closest and draw the line to it but if a new marker is added and is closer than the previously closest marker a new polyline is drawn and the old one is still there.

```
    var sorted = pathArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(a['distance']));
        var bValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(b['distance']));

        if (typeof aValue && bValue == "number") {
            return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
        }

        return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
    });
    console.log(sorted);

    pathCoordinate = [{lat: lat1,  lng: lon1}, {lat: sorted[0].lat, lng: sorted[0].lng}];

    line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pathCoordinate,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    line.setMap(map);
```

I've tried using

```
    line.setMap(null);
```

but to no avail

Comment: Make sure that line variable is define globally.

Comment: Hard to say. Not enough code. "no avail"? We need more details. Are you using Events? If line changes it needs to `.setMap()` again. Non-primitive values can be an issue too.

Comment: Where did you try `line.setMap(null);`?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line exists and has a `setMap` method, set its `map` property to null (remove it from the map) before creating a new line.

```
var sorted = pathArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(a['distance']));
  var bValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(b['distance']));

  if (typeof aValue && bValue == "number") {
    return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
  }

  return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
});
console.log(sorted);

pathCoordinate = [{
  lat: lat1,
  lng: lon1
}, {
  lat: sorted[0].lat,
  lng: sorted[0].lng
}];

if (line && line.setMap) line.setMap(null);
line = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: pathCoordinate,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});

line.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx94w8b1/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var pathArr = [];
var lat1 = 37.4419;
var lon1 = -122.1419;
var line;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  /* pathArr.push({
    lat: 37.4419,
    lng: -122.1419,
    distance: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), map.getCenter()) 
  }); */
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function addPoint(evt) {
  pathArr.push({
    lat: evt.latLng.lat(),
    lng: evt.latLng.lng(),
    distance: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(evt.latLng, map.getCenter())
  });
  var sorted = pathArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(a['distance']));
    var bValue = Math.abs(parseFloat(b['distance']));

    if (typeof aValue && bValue == "number") {
      return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
    }

    return (aValue > bValue) ? 1 : ((bValue > aValue) ? -1 : 0);
  });
  console.log(sorted);

  pathCoordinate = [{
    lat: lat1,
    lng: lon1
  }, {
    lat: sorted[0].lat,
    lng: sorted[0].lng
  }];

  if (line && line.setMap) line.setMap(null);
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: pathCoordinate,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  line.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```